# Can only zip RDDs with same number of elements in each partition : PySpark Mlib

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, apache-spark-mllib

I get `Can only zip RDDs with same number of elements in each partition` on running bisecting k-means on large datasets  . 
I am using spark 2.0.0

Code :

```
data = spark_context.textFile(input_path)
parsed_data = data.map(lambda line: [float(x) for x in line.split(delimiter)])
model = BisectingKMeans.train(parsed_data.map(lambda x: x[1:]), no_clusters, maxIterations=iterations)
pred = model.predict(parsed_data.map(lambda x: x[1:])).collect()
```

The input file is of size 17 GB. 
Note: First field in file is ID , so I am skipping that when i do clustering. 
Spark does zip opearation internally. I think the issue is fixed for ordinary kmeans. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-13178?focusedCommentId=15131436&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-15131436

Comment: Spark does zip opearation internally. I think the issue is fixed for ordinary kmeans. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-13178?focusedCommentId=15131436&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-15131436